# WorksheetFunction.Match multiple sheets Excel VBA error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Getting a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

I have 2 data sets in 2 different sheets.  I'm trying to run a WorksheetFunction.Match in each data set and copy/paste the appropriate columns to 2 new sheets.

ABC data -> ABC works fine but getting error after `Sheets("XYZ data").Select`

```
Sub ccc()

    Sheets("ABC data").Select
    sedol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Sedol", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    isin = WorksheetFunction.Match("Isin", Rows("1:1"), 0)

    Sheets("ABC data").Columns(sedol).Copy Destination:=Sheets("ABC").Range("A1")
    Sheets("ABC data").Columns(isin).Copy Destination:=Sheets("ABC").Range("B1")

    Sheets("XYZ data").Select
    sedol1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("SEDOL1", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    ticker = WorksheetFunction.Match("Ticker", Rows("1:1"), 0)

    Sheets("XYZ data").Columns(sedol1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("XYZ").Range("A1")
    Sheets("XYZ data").Columns(ticker).Copy Destination:=Sheets("XYZ").Range("B1")

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Copy *SEDOL1* from the VBA code sheet then go to the *XYZ Data* worksheet and see if you can find it in the first row with `Ctrl+F` using the *Match entire cell contents* option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get away from `.Select` and `.Activate` and stop relying on a dynamic `ActiveSheet` to define the parent of your ranges.

```
Sub ccc()

    with Sheets("ABC data")
      sedol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Sedol", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
      isin = WorksheetFunction.Match("Isin", .Rows("1:1"), 0)

      .Columns(sedol).Copy Destination:=Sheets("ABC").Range("A1")
      .Columns(isin).Copy Destination:=Sheets("ABC").Range("B1")
    end with

    with Sheets("XYZ data")
      sedol1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("SEDOL1", .Rows("1:1"), 0)
      ticker = WorksheetFunction.Match("Ticker", .Rows("1:1"), 0)

      .Columns(sedol1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("XYZ").Range("A1")
      .Columns(ticker).Copy Destination:=Sheets("XYZ").Range("B1")
    end with

End Sub
```

Note that the prefixing periods (e.g. . or *full stop*) in `.Rows("1:1")` and `.Columns(...)` determine that the parent is the worksheet defined in the `With ... End With` statement.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: I would only add that it looks like he is running similar code repeatedly. I'd be willing to bet there's a way to loop it. We'd need more info on the project and it looks like he filtered it out. If I had to guess he works in public finance.

Comment: @Toby - I agree. A loop through a variant array of worksheet names would be one possibility.

Comment: I'd bet it's every worksheet. The concerning part is the variable string names in the compare. There are a bunch of different ways to handle that though.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comments and suggestions.  I was able to resolve the issue by putting all of my syntax in a workbook.  I had my syntax all under the PMR sheet previously.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Sheets(Name).Select:

```
Sheets("ABC Data").Activate
```

Is my preferred method. I would also recommend creating objects to make it easier for you to type things out:

```
Dim ABC as WorkSheet
Set ABC = ActiveSheet
```

So something like:

```
Dim ABC as Worksheet
Dim XYZ as worksheet

Set ABC = Sheets("ABC data")
With ABC
    sedol = .WorksheetFunction.Match("Sedol", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    isin = .WorksheetFunction.Match("isin", Rows("1:1"), 0)

    .Columns(sedol).Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
    .Columns(isin).Copy Destination:=.Range("B1")
End With

Set XYZ = Sheets("XYZ data")
With XYZ
    sedol1 = .WorksheetFunction.Match("SEDOL1", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    ticker = .WorksheetFunction.Match("Ticker", Rows("1:1"), 0)

    .Columns(sedol1).Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
    .Columns(ticker).Copy Destination:=.Range("B1")
End With
```

Finally, If you are doing this for every sheet in your workbook, you should loop it. If you need that code let me know

If that method of selecting/working with sheets doesn't work for you let me know and Ill update the answer.

Comment: Might be missing the `.` in `.Rows("1:1")`. Don't want to leave that up to a guess. The destinations are different as well.

Comment: The downfalls of copy-pasta. It was a quick and dirty example. You are very likely correct though (unless the rows are on the active sheet and he set them all to 1:1 as a method of filtering proprietary data).

Comment: Hey Toby, I would love to know the loop code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Posting it so other people can learn from my boneheaded move.  Noticed my syntax were all entered in PMR sheet - moved all of my syntax to a module and it worked like a charm.